# How to create a unit test in Python for specific code in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have the following function:

```py
def update_installation_register(
    remote: RemoteRegisterData, install_id: str, data: dict, verify: bool
) -> None:
    """Updates an Installation register"""

    credentials = (remote.auth_user, remote.auth_pass)

    url = f"https://{remote.hostname}/api/instalaciones/{install_id}/"
    resp = requests.put(url=url, auth=credentials, json=data, verify=verify)
    
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        raise RemoteRegisterRequestError()
```

It's part of a existing codebase, and I'm trying to add unit test to it.

I am not figuring out how to create a simple test for it, maybe a test that checks return None if all goes well and to catch an exception if it does not?

I'm not sure how to mock that request, if I write a `test_update_installation_register` for pytest

I am willing to refactor the code if necessary, although I'd prefer to leave it the way it is,

I'm puzzled by how this simple function managed to confuse me this much, but there it is.

The thing is, and maybe this is the fundamental question... How do I test a function that is merely a simple wrapper to a http request, without actually testing the request?

This is the best I could come up with, but I'm not entirely sure this is the right approach

```py
def test_update_installation_register_valid():

    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock:

        remote_register = remote_register_data()
        mock.put(
            f"https://{remote_register.hostname}/api/instalaciones/{req_test_id()}/",
            status_code=200,
        )

        resp = update_installation_register(
            remote_register, req_test_id(), req_test_data(), verify=True
        )

        assert resp == None
```

where

```
remote_register_data()
req_test_id()
req_test_id()
req_test_data()
```

are just returning a hardcoded "test" value

Is this a good solution?

Comment: you're looking for mocking! https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: Essentially, all this function does is structure a query, authenticate, and check for the status code. So it’s going to be hard to test it much besides just mocking requests and making sure the arguments are handled correctly. It seems like you’re off to a great start. This isn’t really a specific question though… it’s possible this would be a good fit for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)!